# How do I fix this inverted mesh?

Tags: mesh, modifiers

I'm having trouble with this project of mine, I wanted to make this cloak fully fluffy but the sides become inverted.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hard to tell from this screenshot. Are the face normals flipped on the sides?

Comment: Not sure exactly what you mean, but you can use ALT+N to flip normals. Let me know if it works.